# How to add outside collaborators to github Repo via terraform

Tags: github, terraform

I am using Terraform to manage access to my Github Repo. I want to add outside collaborators (users that are not part of my Organization) to my Repo and give them readonly rights like this:

```
resource "github_repository_collaborator" "some_user" {
  repository = "repo_name"
  username = "some_user"
  permission = "pull"
}
```

But this code tries to find the user "some_user" in Repo organization, although this user is an outside user under another organization. Is there a way to define organization for this user like maybe as follows:

```
...
username = "new_organization\some_user"
...
```

Or is there another resource that I can use to access outside collaborators?

I am not able to find out how can I do this through Terraform. I have been through the documentation (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/resources/repository_collaborator) many times but can't find the relevant information.

Can someone help?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I have tried to create github team with all the outside collaborators and when that didn't work i tried to add the collaborators directly to the repo through terraform. But whatever I do it tries to find the user under my Organization. And obviously can't find them.

Comment: I have updated the question! Maybe now it is clearer what I am trying to achieve and what I have tried so far.

Comment: Looks like this is a missing feature, best you can do is report it: https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/issues

Comment: Is there a workaround?